# GNU find, how to use debug options, -D

Tags: linux, find

I've been using find more successfully in my daily work especially with xargs, parallel, grep and pcregrep.

I was reading the man pages for find tonight and found a section I'd always skipped right over...Debug options.

I promptly tried:

```
find -D help
# then 
find -D tree . -type f -name "fjdalfj"
# and
find -D search . -type f -name "fjaldkj"
```

Wow some really interesting output....however I was unsuccessful in tracking down what this means.

Can someone point me to a resource I can read about this or perhaps they care to explain a bit about how they would use these options or when they'd be useful.

Comment: Look into the source code of GNU find. It is free software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora '$ man find' provides illumination.  Notice carefully where the "-D" options are placed: before the selection expression and before the search directories are listed.  Most of the debug mode deals with how the selection expressions are parsed, as these can get quite involved.

- tree: shows the generated parse tree for the expression.
- search: verbosely log the navigation of the searched directories.
- stat: trace calls to stat(2) and friends when getting the file attributes, such as its size.
- rates: indicate how frequently each expression predicate is successful.
- opt: provide details on how the selection expression was optimized after it is parsed.
- exec: show details about the -exec, -execdir, and -okdir programs run.

You mileage may vary, your version of find(1) may have different debug options.  A '$ find -D help' is probably in order.

Comment: That's a start...The placement of the args is important to notice...The search output makes some sense, I can see things like, "isdir=0". The tree output is pretty far out to me. Thanks for taking time to add your thoughts.